# Stripping last comma from PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

I'm wondering how I can remove the trailing comma in this foreach loop in my PHP script running inside of javascript.

```
<html>                                                                                                                                                                              
      <head>                                                                                                                                                                            
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>                                                                                                     
    <script type='text/javascript'>                                                                                                                                                 
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});                                                                                                                 
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);                                                                                                                                      

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country','Blocks'],
  <?php
    foreach ($bans as $key => $value)
                print"['$key', $value],\n";
    ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
                    backgroundColor : '#555555',
                    colors : ['#FFFF00', '#FF0000']
                    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This causes a problem as I get a trailing comma, I've tried an implode method and rtrim method but none of those appear to be working (I've also never used those functions so I may be doing it wrong)

My implode method was:

```
<?php
    $resultstr = array();
    foreach ($bans as $key => $value)
                print"['$key', $value],\n";
  $resultstr = implode(",", $resultstr);
    ?>
```

My rtrim method was:

```
  <?php
  $resultstr = array();
    foreach ($bans as $key => $value)
                print"['$key', $value],\n";
  echo rtrim($resultstr, ",");
    ?>
```

When compiled it looks like this:

```
    <html>
```

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

```
  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country','Blocks'],
  ['Japan', 11],
['United States', 45],
['Argentina', 1],
         ]);

    var options = {
                    backgroundColor : '#555555',
                    colors : ['#FFFF00', '#FF0000']
                    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should do instead of trimming the string afterwards is not generating the trailing comma at all:

```
$not_first = false;
foreach ($bans as $key => $value) {
    if ($not_first) {
        print(", ");
    }
    $not_first = true;
    print "['$key', $value]\n";
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks so much for that (3 more minutes until I can accept your response as the answer.)

Answer (score 4):

This could be another approach:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php
$table = array(array('Country', 'Blocks'));
foreach($bans as $key => $value) {
    $table[] = array($key, $value);
}
echo json_encode($table);
?>);
```

I often use json_encode so I don't have to take care of escaping all the values.

Answer (score 2):

You missed something:

```
echo rtrim($resultstr, ",");
```

You could also do:

```
echo substr($resultstr, 0, -1);
```

Comment: I just tried both of those at the end of my PHP script, and the script result is still the same when viewing the HTML source of the site, adding compiled source to original question.

Comment: @user1848130 Try my solution as well, might help.

Comment: Agreed. Definately smarter not have the trailing comma in the first place, also using json_encode as suggested by @vstm is a good idea.

Comment: i guess implode is way much easier for this approach

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array that contains the `[key, value]` pieces and then glue them with `implode`:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr['key1'] = 'val1';
$arr['key2'] = 'val2';
$arr['key3'] = 'val3';

function PrepareValues(&$item, $key) {
    $item = "['$key', $item]";
}
array_walk_recursive($arr, "PrepareValues");
$resultstr = implode(",\n", $arr);
print($resultstr);
?>
```

**Output**

```
['key1', val1],
['key2', val2],
['key3', val3]
```